# connecting socket to host that has username and password in c#

Tags: c#, sockets

I create a socket by this code:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
```

I want connect this socket to host that has username and password. I have user and pass and IP of this host.But I don't know how to connect to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to specify what protocol you're communicating in.

On the TCP level you just connect to the host, then you start talking in that protocol (HTTP for instance) and supply username/password using the rules defined for that protocol (for instance, [basic authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)).

On the TCP level there is no authentication.

When using HTTP you could alternatively use [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which allows communicating on a higher level than socket, it has all this built in (the `Credentials` property) and there are plenty of examples online.

Comment: protocol HTTP , port 80

Comment: Is there any other way like socket?

Comment: @user2855778 you should provide that information in your question, not as a comment to my answer. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: :thanks. I want to to get packets from this host. this host is IP camera that send pictures continuously..